# My angular website won't link to my css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have started to use angular, and I have got a basic folder structure where i have got my idenx.html file in the src folder and then i have got css the css folder, where my style sheet is, but it is not linking to my style sheet.

I have tried everything from searching google, tutorials and even on here, but nothing seems to work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/redstargames.min.css">
```

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a trivial problem. There are tons of solutions and explanations out there. You didn't put enough effort. Please read more about asking such questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

add in angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "src/css/redstargames.min.css",
   .......
],
```

Comment: I did but no change ```"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/css/redstargames.min.css"
            ],```

Comment: the path should be css/redstargames.min.css

Comment: Yeah, but my css folder is inside the src folder

Comment: correct path should be from src  folder, not the src/css/redstargames.min.css  [you can refer styles.css also it's in src folder but path styles.css]

Answer (score 0):

If you use Angular CLI  you have to add your CSS to .angular-cli.json.
For example:

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/angular2-busy/build/style/busy.css",
   "styles.css"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In your angular.json update like this

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "src/assets/css/redstargames.min.css"
        ],
```

Then remove this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/redstargames.min.css">
```